# How can I create another user login block?

Tags: users

I would like the user login block to be standard on the front page, but a link on all other pages. The best way I can think of doing this is having two blocks and restrict them through the block setting.

Is there another way to do this? I have considered fancy login since that gives another login block, but I was curious if it's possible to clone the core login block. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have the option assign a block to different region.But you can use the [Multiblock](http://drupal.org/project/multiblock)

it will allowing you to create multiple Block Instances of already existing blocks.

If you want customize the login block with your own design, then [this link](http://www.advomatic.com/blogs/amanda-luker/theming-user-login-block) will help you.

Comment: The multiblock module seems to be what I want. Thanks for showing me!

Answer (score 1):

You could also just restrict the standard login block to the front page and create a block with a simple link to `user` in it and have that placed everywhere else, eg:

```
return l('Click here to login','user');
```

or

```
<div id="my-non-front-page-login">
 <a href="/user">Click here to login</a>
</div>
```

inserted either from a module's hook_block() (first way) or from the Block Admin Page's create block (second way)

Comment: Good point. I might end doing it that way if the multiblock module doesn't pan out. Thanks for the tip!